# Is "House of Awesome" a correct name?

Tags: adjectives

I'm having a friendly argument about whether "House of Awesome" is a grammatically correct name, or if it's wrong and should be corrected to "House of the Awesome"/"House of Awesomeness". Can you help me?

Comment: How can a name be "incorrect"?  Of course "House of Awesome" is a correct name.

Comment: I mean grammatically

Comment: Same thing. Grammar and spelling don't come into names, or we would never have had *Inglourious Basterds*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about names are off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If there is a **specific** question about a **particular** point of grammar here, please feel free to edit the question to make that explicit.

Comment: 'House of AAAAAAAAAwsummm&t$gg' cannot be labelled 'grammatically incorrect'. Ghastly, certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"House of Awesome" sounds way better to me than "House of the Awesome". To me, the second one sounds like something a non-native speaker would come up with, since often the definite article is used before abstract nouns in other languages in situations where it is not in English.

Technically, "House of the Awesome" could be grammatically correct if "Awesome" is interpreted as an adjective standing for a group of people described by that adjective (as in e.g. "[The House of the Dead](https://books.google.com/books?id=6ddZUYGjcW4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22house%20of%20the%20dead%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizloeBwa7RAhWm6oMKHXBuC9MQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=%22house%20of%20the%20dead%22&f=false)") but it took me a moment to think of this interpretation. I don't think it's very natural.

"House of Awesomeness" is also OK, but to me it doesn't have the same pizazz. There is a published book called "[The Book of Awesome](https://books.google.com/books?id=huekDAAAQBAJ&pg=PP3&dq=%22of%20awesome%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-7POxwa7RAhWk34MKHS_bAfgQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22of%20awesome%22&f=false)".

Converting an adjective to an abstract noun like this is certainly informal and not ordinary grammar, but it's not that uncommon in colloquial English when constructing a catchy phrase or title. Another example is National Geographic's "[Science of Stupid](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/science-of-stupid/)".